# Disjointing the Gershgorin Disks

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

is there a way to transform matrices with non-disjoint C into similar matrices with disjoint gershgorin disks?
What I am looking for is a way to find the eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix, using strum theorem.
I tought if I could add A with a multiple of the identity matrix, but that just shifts the disks. any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "add A with factor of the unitary matrix"?

Comment: Why not try some variant of Geršgorin's circle theorem  like [Brauer's ovals theorem](http://planetmath.org/brauersovalstheorem)? For even higher order version of that, a good starting point is Chapter 2 of R.S.Varga's book [Geršgorin and His Circles](https://www.amazon.com/Gerschgorin-His-Circles-Richard-Varga/dp/3540211004).

Comment: I meant calculating $A+p*I$ for some p, since the eigenvalues are just the eigenvalues of A+p. @Omnomnomnom

Comment: Okay, so you meant "add $A$ with a *multiple* of the *identity* matrix"

Comment: edited, thanks.@Omnomnomnom